# Statistical anomaly or is there someone who doesn't like me?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I'm not immune to downvotes, far from it, but I don't typically get many and usually only on new answers.  The last few days I've had more than the usual number of downvotes on old questions, like 2-3 per day.  I'm left wondering if it's just a statistical anomaly or something more sinister.  Anyone else experiencing more than the usual number of downvotes recently?

Comment: I don't like you :] But dislike is not a good downvoting reason. Have you tried to use the normal process already? Flagging for a mod and giving him a list of the posts?

Comment: No. I'm getting a lot of *upvotes* on old answers, but I suspect that's because of the moderator election.

Comment: I don't like you, but I didn't downvote you (despite what my meta-name may tell you)

Comment: ...and FWIW, I'm capped today, so this isn't a plea for people to go find stuff they can upvote for me.  Please don't.

Comment: Thanks for the love, probably a good thing I avoided the moderator nomination thread.

Comment: Just kidding, I like you

Comment: I would have totally voted for you in the nominator moderation thread!  [sic]

Comment: I noticed some strange flagging earlier (which the mods have since cleaned up), not sure if it's related.

Comment: I got 5 near-simultaneous yesterday, definitely a targeting thing.

Answer (score 3):

> Statistical anomaly or is there someone who doesn’t like me?

Yes.

> Anyone else experiencing more than the usual number of downvotes recently?

Probably, but not me.  It's a rare day that I get a downvote on SO, but [as you can see](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2915?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top) I haven't been contributing much since May of last year, and have instead been living off the interest of my existing posts.

However, if you are concerned, flag one of your posts for moderator attention and explain that you believe above-normal downvotes have been occurring on your account.  Be aware that if you make such a request then you may experience a rep-recalc.  This might result in a greater rep-loss than the spurious downvotes caused.

Comment: If it were 4-5 I'd probably bug a moderator as that seems like too big a blip.  Most days I don't see any either and only rarely on old questions, especially ones that have been previous upvoted.  2-3 is in the mild paranoia range so I thought I'd check to see if it's a general phenomena or just me.

Answer (score 1):

Not really (*knock on wood*).

I've been going through questions and voting on them to get that damned Electorate badge. Maybe others are doing the same? (Although legitimately, unless you ask a lot of questions, you shouldn't be seeing *that* many)

Comment: Nah.  These are old answers, I don't have many questions.  The weird thing is I delete almost all of my answers that people don't find useful (downvoted initially) because I don't see any point in leaving junk laying around.  These are downvotes on previously upvoted answers.

Answer (score 1):

Are the answers you're getting downvoted on posted by any of the nominated moderators, or do they have other answers by those people? I've been getting upvotes on a few of my old questions and answers, most likely due to my profile being linked from the moderator elections. It could be that those old threads are getting more attention, and people just disagree with the answers you provided for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen it happen from time to time...  However, there are days where I get quite a few upvotes on really old questions/answers that probably offset some of those haters out there...